# Unity lost almost all Assembly references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have an unity project in which I added an external .dll via NuGet.
After that my project lost almost all assembly references. (Error CS0234)

- I tried reimporting all assets.
- I deleted the Library-Folder and let it rebuild and reinsert the deleted one.
- I checked the manifest.json; It contains "com.unity.modules.ui": "1.0.0", .

Since the Unity Editor and Visual Studio throw me that error I can't run the project.[image: A small selection of error-messages. Since they are all the same.]

Can I rebuild the assembly references in any way, so I can save my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution:

The problem:

You need to insert the .dll you wan't to access into your Asset folder. I did that. I simply took the whole constructed folder hierachy from the NuGet installation folder.
There were multiple versions of the same .dll in there. Also there was a .xml file with assembly code in it.

The solution:
Just copy the .dll and avoid multiple dlls and the xml file. Unity will take care of that itself.

If you lost your assembly references, take a backup of the manifest.json from the Package folder and replace the corrupt one.